# Is there a definitive table for the number of kills for each weapon level?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

In MW3, is there a table for each game type (domination, S&D, etc) and gun type (M4, Barrett, etc) that tells you how many kills for each level upgrade of the weapon?

Answer (score 1):

To see how many kills did you make with some particular weapon you can do the following:

- Go to "Create a Class"
- Click `F1` to open Assignments(?)(dunno how it's called, got localized version of MW3)
- In that window click on the `All Assignments` button at the bottom
- Then you can choose `Main Weapons` or `Secondary Weapons`
- Then you choose a type of the weapon that you like
- Choose the weapon itself
- Look at the assignments(i.e. "Kill 100 enemies with that weapon") and at the progress(i.e. `98/100`). That will show you the total kills of that weapon.

Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

With Call Of Duty Elite, you can see your stats by game type and by gun. It won't be precise enough to give you your number of kills for each level of your weapon though.

I don't know if you can access those stats from within the game, but you can on Elite.

Comment: Hello. Your answer does not provide info to this particular question, but answers possibly a question to another game.